# Setup mail using PHP and CPanel

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I'm trying to learn how emails works.

I have a form in an HTML, and a PHP script that sends that email
here is my php code, hardcoded just for testing:

```
    $for     = 'mymail@gmail.com';
    $title   = 'Some Title';
    $msg     = 'Some text';
    $headers = 'From: email@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: email@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($for, $title, $msg, $headers);
```

So, I have bought a "hosting" for my site, using CPanel
And I want to send the information of the users that fill my contact
form to my own email.

But It isn't working, so I went to "Email Trace" on Cpanel and I 
got this error:

> "587 X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 CV=no
>   DN="/L=Cluster/O=anti-spam-premium.com/OU=Domain/CN=fs.anti-spam-premium.com/emailAddress=postmaster@fs.anti-spam-premium.com":
>   SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 Subject con"

What do I must setup in CPanel?

Any idea?

Comment: The error finishes "... data: 550 Subject con" or it has more than that?

Comment: Better you should contact your hosting provider. Only they can help you to fix this problem. Without knowing server configurations, we can only predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with CPanel's email trace but if the error code you get is that 550 I'm seeing then these SMTP Error messages concern the recipient's email address.

They usually define a non-existent email address on the remote side. Though it can be returned also by the recipient's firewall (or when the incoming server is down), the great majority of errors 550 simply tell that the recipient email address doesn't exist. You should contact the recipient otherwise and get the right address or just try another to be sure.

Also check that your server's IP isn't on any international spam blocklist.